# Consultar resultados utilizando SQL ou dicas sobre programação em XAILER

Tags: sql, firebird, clipper

Tenho a seguinte relação entre 3 tabelas:

```
'SELECT contareceber.codcontareceber, contareceber.codorganizacao, 
contareceber.dtdocumento, contareceber.dtvencimento, 
contareceber.valortotalbruto, contareceber.valortotalrecebido, 
contareceber.dtcancelamento, contareceberquitacao.dtquitacao 
FROM contareceber 
LEFT JOIN contareceberquitacaoitem ON 
contareceberquitacaoitem.codcontareceber = contareceber.codcontareceber 
LEFT JOIN contareceberquitacao ON 
contareceberquitacao.codcontareceberquitacao = 
contareceberquitacaoitem.codcontareceberquitacao 
WHERE contareceber.dtdocumento>='+ValToSQL(::oDataInicial:Value)+' and 
contareceber.dtdocumento<='+ValToSQL(::oDataFinal:Value)+' 
ORDER BY contareceber.codorganizacao'
```

Sendo essa ::oDataInicial:Value e ::oDataFinal:Value são os valores de data que o usuario vai digitar no meu programa, fiz apenas um programa para executar esse **SELECT** e me trazer as informações que eu preciso em uma tabela temporária.

Depois que eu tenho essas informações eu preciso de entregar os seguintes dados:
(seja por meio de um outro comando SQL ou qualquer outra forma.)

- TITULOS
- TITULOS PAGOS
- TITULOS EM ABERTO
- PAGOS EM DIA
- PAGOS EM ATÉ 30 DIAS
- PAGOS ENTRE 30 E 60 DIAS
- PAGOS ENTRE 60 e 90 DIAS
- PAGOS ENTRE 90 E 120 DIAS
- PAGOS ENTRE 120 E 180 DIAS
- PAGOS COM MAIS DE 180 DIAS

O temporario é criado desta forma:

```
DBCreate('TEMPORARIO.DBF',{{'CODRECEB'   ,'C',12,0},; //codigo do contas a receber
                           {'CODORG'     ,'C', 3,0},; //codigo da empresa
                           {'DTDOC'      ,'D', 8,0},; //data de emissao
                           {'DTVENC'     ,'D', 8,0},; //data de vencimento
                           {'VLRTOT'     ,'N',10,2},; //valor total bruto
                           {'VLRTREC'    ,'N',12,2},; //valor total recebido
                           {'DTCANC'     ,'D', 8,0},; //data cancelamento
                           {'DTQUIT'     ,'D', 8,0},; //data quitação
                           {'PRAZO'      ,'N',10,0},; //prazo em dias para quitar
                           {'DIASATEPAG' ,'N',10,0},; //qtd de dias até pagar
                           {'EXCEDENTE'  ,'N',10,0}}) //quantos dias passou do prazo
```

Eu tenho essas informações para comparar e trazer os resultados das datas.
Sobre as tabelas que eu estou buscando, elas tem esta estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTARECEBER (
CODCONTARECEBER          VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODORGANIZACAO           VARCHAR(3) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
STTIPOCONTARECEBER       VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
DTDOCUMENTO              DATE,
DTVENCIMENTO             DATE,
SEQUENCIALPARCELA        INTEGER,
STMANUALSISTEMA          VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
NUMERODOCUMENTO          VARCHAR(20) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
VALORTOTALBRUTO          NUMERIC(10,2),
VALORTOTALJUROS          NUMERIC(8,2),
VALORTOTALDESCONTO       NUMERIC(8,2),
VALORTOTALRECEBIDO       NUMERIC(12,2),
OBSERVACAO               VARCHAR(50) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODVENDA                 VARCHAR(15) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODCLIENTE               VARCHAR(10) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CPFCNPJ                  VARCHAR(14) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODCHEQUE                VARCHAR(10) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODCONVENIO              VARCHAR(8) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODCARTAO                VARCHAR(6) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
NUMEROTEF                VARCHAR(20) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODUSUARIO               VARCHAR(8) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
ST_EXPORT                VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
DTULTIMAATUALIZACAO      DATE,
HRULTIMAATUALIZACAO      TIME,
STCANCELADA              VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODUSUARIOCANCELAMENTO   VARCHAR(8) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
DTCANCELAMENTO           DATE,
HRCANCELAMENTO           TIME,
STVENDAFINANCIADA        VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODFORMAPAGTO            VARCHAR(2) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
OBSDEVOLUCAOPRODUTO      BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 80,
ORGORIGEMATUALIZACAO     VARCHAR(3) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
ID_REP_ORIGEM            BIGINT
);


CREATE TABLE CONTARECEBERQUITACAOITEM (
CODCONTARECEBERQUITACAO  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODCONTARECEBER          VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
VALORJUROS               NUMERIC(8,2),
VALORRECEBIDO            NUMERIC(8,2),
VALORDESCONTO            NUMERIC(8,2),
ST_EXPORT                VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
DTULTIMAATUALIZACAO      DATE,
HRULTIMAATUALIZACAO      TIME,
ORGORIGEMATUALIZACAO     VARCHAR(3) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
ID_REP_ORIGEM            BIGINT
);

CREATE TABLE CONTARECEBERQUITACAO (
CODCONTARECEBERQUITACAO       VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODUSUARIO                    VARCHAR(8) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODORGANIZACAO                VARCHAR(3) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
STTIPOQUITACAO                VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
STFORMAPAGTO                  VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODFUNCIONARIO                VARCHAR(7) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODCLIENTE                    VARCHAR(10) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODCONVENIO                   VARCHAR(8) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODCARTAO                     VARCHAR(6) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
DTQUITACAO                    DATE,
HRQUITACAO                    TIME,
STCOBRARJUROS                 VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
PERCJUROS                     NUMERIC(5,2),
PERCMULTA                     NUMERIC(5,2),
STACERTOAUTOMATICO            VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
STATUALIZARPRECOATUAL         VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
VALORTOTAL                    NUMERIC(10,2),
VALORDESCONTO                 NUMERIC(10,2),
VALORTOTALJUROS               NUMERIC(10,2),
STCANCELADA                   VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
DTCANCELAMENTO                DATE,
HRCANCELAMENTO                TIME,
CODUSUARIOCANCELAMENTO        VARCHAR(8) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODLANCAMENTOCONTAFINANCEIRA  VARCHAR(10) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
ST_EXPORT                     VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
DTULTIMAATUALIZACAO           DATE,
HRULTIMAATUALIZACAO           TIME,
STCHEQUETERCEIROS             VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
OBSCANCELAMENTO               BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 80,
NR_ACERTO                     VARCHAR(8) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODECF                        VARCHAR(8) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
NUMEROCOO                     VARCHAR(6) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
NUMEROGNF                     VARCHAR(6) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
CODSESSAOECFTEF               VARCHAR(15) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
STCUPOMECFCANCELADO           VARCHAR(1) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
ORGORIGEMATUALIZACAO          VARCHAR(3) COLLATE WIN_PTBR,
ID_REP_ORIGEM                 BIGINT
);
```

Comment: Você tem como informar qual a estrutura da tabela em questão? Porque o que você precisa é adicionar mais filtros no seu WHERE, porém sem saber quais são os campos, fica difícil determinar o que você vai colocar.

Comment: Tem sim, vou adicionar na pergunta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom vou fazer uma tradução aqui do que você disse que precisa:

- **TITULOS** - Seriam todos os titulos, dentro do filtro que você já determinou.
- **TITULOS PAGOS** - Seriam todos os titulos, dentro do filtro, e que tenham a DTQUITACAO diferente de nulo
- **TITULOS EM ABERTO** - Seriam todos os titulos, dentro do filtro, e com a DTQUITACAO com valor nulo
- **PAGOS EM DIA** - Seriam todos os titulos, dentro do filtro, e com a DTQUITACAO menor ou igual a DTVENCIMENTO.
- **PAGOS EM ATÉ ... ENTRE ... COM MAIS** - Seriam todo os títulos, dentro do filtro, que tenham a DTQUITACAO diferente de nulo e com a quantidade de dias dentro de um período referente a DTVENCIMENTO. (Essa não ficou muito claro se era isso mesmo que gostaria, corrija-me se eu estiver errado).

Diante disso os respectivos SQLs dentro do que deu pra captar do seu banco de dados seriam:

TITULOS:

```
SELECT CONTARECEBER.CODCONTARECEBER,
       CONTARECEBER.CODORGANIZACAO,
       CONTARECEBER.DTDOCUMENTO,
       CONTARECEBER.DTVENCIMENTO,
       CONTARECEBER.VALORTOTALBRUTO,
       CONTARECEBER.VALORTOTALRECEBIDO,
       CONTARECEBER.DTCANCELAMENTO,
       CONTARECEBERQUITACAO.DTQUITACAO
FROM CONTARECEBER
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTARECEBERQUITACAOITEM ON
       CONTARECEBER.CODCONTARECEBER = CONTARECEBERQUITACAOITEM.CODCONTARECEBER
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTARECEBERQUITACAO ON
       CONTARECEBERQUITACAOITEM.CODCONTARECEBERQUITACAO = CONTARECEBERQUITACAO.CODCONTARECEBERQUITACAO
WHERE CONTARECEBER.DTDOCUMENTO BETWEEN :DataInicial AND :DataFinal
ORDER BY CONTARECEBER.CODORGANIZACAO
```

Os outros vou mudar somente o **WHERE** para simplificar.

TITULOS PAGOS:

```
WHERE CONTARECEBER.DTDOCUMENTO BETWEEN :DataInicial AND :DataFinal
AND CONTARECEBERQUITACAO.DTQUITACAO IS NOT NULL
```

TITULOS EM ABERTO:

```
WHERE CONTARECEBER.DTDOCUMENTO BETWEEN :DataInicial AND :DataFinal
AND CONTARECEBERQUITACAO.DTQUITACAO IS NULL
```

PAGOS EM DIA:

```
WHERE CONTARECEBER.DTDOCUMENTO BETWEEN :DataInicial AND :DataFinal
AND CONTARECEBERQUITACAO.DTQUITACAO <= CONTARECEBER.DTVENCIMENTO
```

PAGOS EM ATÉ ... ENTRE ... COM MAIS

```
WHERE CONTARECEBER.DTDOCUMENTO BETWEEN :DataInicial AND :DataFinal
AND CONTARECEBERQUITACAO.DTQUITACAO IS NOT NULL 
AND CONTARECEBER.DTVENCIMENTO BETWEEN '2017-06-08' AND '2017-07-08'
```

Sendo esse último exemplo buscando de hoje até 30 dias para frente, basta adapta-lo as situações que você citou. Isso é claro se entendi certo essa sua última necessidade.

Comment: As 4 primeiras soluções me serviram muito bem, se tiver alguma forma de me retornar os valores somados também, tem registros no codcontareceber que se repete.

A Quinta solução, eu não entendi bem...
por que tipo, tem que ser 30 dias a partir da data de vencimento.. pro que temos os que foram pagos em dia... como eu faria para somar 30 dias nas datas de vencimento?

Comment: Acho que agora entendi o que você deseja. Testa por favor o seguinte comando:

WHERE CONTARECEBER.DTDOCUMENTO BETWEEN :DataInicial AND :DataFinal
    AND CONTARECEBERQUITACAO.DTQUITACAO IS NOT NULL 
    AND CONTARECEBER.DTVENCIMENTO BETWEEN CONTARECEBER.DTVENCIMENTO AND DATEADD(30 day to CONTARECEBER.DTVENCIMENTO)

Usando a função DATEADD da pra adicionar um período ao campo.